# Why does my Bootstrap and/or CSS look different on localhost:8000 than on 127001:8000 for my Django website? And how can I fix this issue?

Tags: django, localhost, django-staticfiles, django-bootstrap3, django-bootstrap4

For some reason my website looks different for both ports. Here is what I mean

[image: 127.0.0.1:8000]

[image: localhost:8000]

Comment: are you sure its not a cache problem? maybe a cached version of your css file is being served in one of them

Comment: I also think that it might be cache problem. Try hard refreshing by pressing F5 key.

Comment: and if hard refresh doesn't work i recommend using Firefox browser private window. It clears everything after closing the window

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Clearing my cache didn't seem to work but Firefox did!